# Library and sample application in the same repository

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm working on a Clojure library, and I'd like to include a sample application in the same repository for demonstration and testing purposes. Ideally the sample application would be in a subdirectory (with the main library in the root) and would use the version of the library that's in the repository (i.e., if I modify the library I don't have to push to Maven before testing it with the sample application).

Things I've considered:

- `lein-sub` seems to require the application to be in the repository's root with the library in a subdirectory, which is the opposite of what I need.
- Checkouts require a symlink and are not meant to be committed to source control.

Is there a way to say (the equivalent of) `:deps ["../../project.clj"]`?

Answer (score 0):

The re-frame library [has something similar](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/blob/master/examples/todomvc/project.clj) to this, but also depends on the clojars stuff:

```
  :cljsbuild {:builds {:client {:source-paths ["src" "../../src"]
                                :compiler     {:output-dir "resources/public/js"
                                               :output-to  "resources/public/js/client.js"}}}})
```

Having said that, I don't see anything wrong with a repo that contains the library source in one subdir and an example application in another subdir.  Both of them would be separate `lein` projects, and the example app could indeed have a `./checkouts` subdir with a symlink that points to the root of the lib project.